# CloseQuoteRequest throwing exception

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am trying to close a quote in MSCRM using C# CloseQuoteRequest.

```
CloseQuoteRequest closeQuoteRequest = new CloseQuoteRequest()
{
    QuoteClose = new QuoteClose()
    {
        QuoteId = quote.ToEntityReference(),
        Subject = "Quote Close " + DateTime.Now.ToString(),
    },
    Status = new OptionSetValue(-1),
    RequestName = "CloseQuote",
};
Service.Execute(closeQuoteRequest);
```

I am getting the error;

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
>   There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:request. The
>   InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 711. Element
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value'
>   contains data from a type that maps to the name
>   'CRM.Entities.Entities:QuoteClose'. The deserializer has no knowledge
>   of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the
>   implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver
>   to return a non-null value for name 'QuoteClose' and namespace
>   'CRM.Entities.Entities'.'.  Please see InnerException for more
>   details.

There is no inner exception for me to see.

Comment: Try not setting the `RequestName` property. I haven't tried it, but the documentation says this is "required, but is supplied by derived classes.(Inherited from OrganizationRequest.)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this was the case but adding .ToEntity() to the QuoteClose Entity worked.

```
CloseQuoteRequest closeQuoteRequest = new CloseQuoteRequest()
{
    QuoteClose = new QuoteClose()
    {
        QuoteId = quote.ToEntityReference(),
        Subject = "Quote Close " + DateTime.Now.ToString(),
    }.ToEntity<Entity>(),
    Status = new OptionSetValue(-1),
    RequestName = "CloseQuote",
};
Service.Execute(closeQuoteRequest);
```

Comment: Did you try removing the `RequestName` property?

Answer (score 1):

Code sample from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.closequoterequest.aspx#Properties) don’t have `RequestName = "CloseQuote"` property being set as it’s not needed. Remove it.

```
// Close the quote
CloseQuoteRequest closeQuoteRequest = new CloseQuoteRequest()
{
    QuoteClose = new QuoteClose()
    {
        QuoteId = closeQuote.ToEntityReference(),
        Subject = "Quote Close " + DateTime.Now.ToString()
    },
    Status = new OptionSetValue(-1)
};
_serviceProxy.Execute(closeQuoteRequest);
```

> **RequestName**
>   Gets or sets the name of the request. Required, but is supplied by derived classes.(Inherited from OrganizationRequest.)
>
> **Status**
>   The Status property corresponds to the Quote.StatusCode attribute. It is shown as “Status Reason” in the Microsoft Dynamics 365 application. If you set the value of this property to -1, the system sets the appropriate corresponding status value.

Answer (score 0):

```
WinQuoteRequest winQuoteRequest = new WinQuoteRequest();
Entity wonQuoteClose = new Entity("quoteclose");
wonQuoteClose.Attributes["quoteid"] = new EntityReference("quote", id);
wonQuoteClose.Attributes["subject"] = "Quote Close" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
winQuoteRequest.QuoteClose = wonQuoteClose;
winQuoteRequest.Status = new OptionSetValue(-1);
service.Execute(winQuoteRequest);
```

Comment: If Your Object Not Properly define Or Either THrow The Error Please Use This Code,

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.